# How to use Distinct option to filter the value of a Column Name that is related to different foreign Keys. C# .NET Lambda LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, lambda

I have a table called campaign which has a foreign key from a table called Snapshot.

I want to bring the records from the table Campaigns and for each foreign key (SnapShotID) to distinct them by the column CampaignName. So from the Foreign Key SnapShotID I want to use the DatasetID and then distinct by the CampaignName.

If I use distinctBy instead of distinct, if a campaignName belongs to different foreign Keys it will distinct them in all cases. However I want to distinct the value of the campaignName that corresponds to the same DatasetID

*Concluding, as an outcome I am trying to*: I have a campaignName called Upstream which belongs to foreign key (SnapshotID) 1,2 and 5. SnapshotID 1 and 2 corresponds to Planning and 5 corresponds to Production. So, I want to bring all records and filter the campaign name for each DataSetID. So Upstream should come twice. One that is connected to Production and one that is connected to Planning. However Upstream in Planning it will be distincted as it exists twice.

**Snapshot Table**

[image: Snapshot Table]

**Campaign Table**

[image: Campaign Table]

As sample: I tried

```
var campaigns = db.Campaigns.Include(c => c.Snapshot)
                                        .OrderBy(i => i.Snapshot.DatasetID)
                                        .ThenBy(i => i.CampaignName.Distinct());
```

The above one throws me an exception => DbDistinctExpression requires a collection argument.
Parameter name: argument

```
var campaigns = db.Campaigns.Include(c => c.Snapshot)
                                    .GroupBy(i => i.Snapshot.DatasetID)
                                    .Select(i => i.CampaignName.Distinct());
```

The above does not compile
So, I tried many combinations but also did not work.

If it is possible i would like help so that the query to be written mainly in lambda and then the same query in LINQ

Comment: Try `.Select(i => new {i.Key, i.Select(c => c.CampaignName).Distinct()})` for second one.

Comment: @GuruStron Just tried it: 
`var campaigns = db.Campaigns.Include(c => c.Snapshot).GroupBy(i => i.Snapshot.DatasetID).Select(i => new { i.Key, i.Select(c => c.CampaignName).Distinct() });`

and does not compile. throws message ->
_Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access._

Comment: Sorry, add some name to `i.Select`:  `.Select(i => new {i.Key,  Names = i.Select(c => c.CampaignName).Distinct()})`

Comment: @GuruStron that one compiled. However `var campaigns` it will be an IQueryable of string Campaign. I want to filter it with the distinct and the result of `var campaigns` to be an IEnumerable or IQueryable of Campaigns in order to display to the related View

Comment: Please add desired output.

Comment: @GuruStron The output shall be all the records from the Campaigns Table in order to be displayed to the related View, but the column CampaignName it will be distincted for each DatasetID from the Table Snapshots. Check the above screenshots to have an overview of the entities. e.g. The CampaignName Upstream should come twice. One that is connected to Production (see foreign key SnapshotID) and one that is connected to Planning (see foreign key SnapshotID). However Upstream in Planning it will be distincted as it exists twice.

Comment: could you check my new answer to the post and see what i am trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I simulated your database with classes to show correct syntax.  You have to check that creation date is between start and end dates.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataBase db = new DataBase()
            {
                Snapshot = new List<Snapshot>() {
                    new Snapshot() { Id = 1, CreationDate = new DateTime(2019, 10, 1, 8,0,0),  DatasetID = "Planning"},
                    new Snapshot() { Id = 2, CreationDate = new DateTime(2019, 10, 2, 8,0,0),  DatasetID = "Planning"},
                    new Snapshot() { Id = 3, CreationDate = new DateTime(2019, 10, 15, 13,0,0),  DatasetID = "Production"},
                    new Snapshot() { Id = 4, CreationDate = new DateTime(2019, 10, 16, 14,0,0),  DatasetID = "Production"},
                    new Snapshot() { Id = 5, CreationDate = new DateTime(2019, 10, 16, 17,0,0),  DatasetID = "Production"}
                },
                Campaign = new List<Campaign>() {
                    new Campaign() { Id = 1, CampaignName = "Upstream",  StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 1, 8,0,0), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 2, 17,0,0), SnapshotID = 1},
                    new Campaign() { Id = 2, CampaignName = "Downstream",  StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 3, 8,0,0), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 6, 15,0,0), SnapshotID = 2},
                    new Campaign() { Id = 3, CampaignName = "Upstream",  StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 1, 10,0,0), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 2, 18,0,0), SnapshotID = 2},
                    new Campaign() { Id = 4, CampaignName = "BufferPrep",  StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 1, 6,0,0), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 5, 15,0,0), SnapshotID = 3},
                    new Campaign() { Id = 5, CampaignName = "Product1",  StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 6, 8,0,0), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 7, 19,0,0), SnapshotID = 4},
                    new Campaign() { Id = 6, CampaignName = "Product2",  StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 8, 8,0,0), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 9, 20,0,0), SnapshotID = 5},
                    new Campaign() { Id = 7, CampaignName = "BufferPrep",  StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 1, 12,0,0), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 6, 10,0,0), SnapshotID = 5},
                    new Campaign() { Id = 9, CampaignName = "Upstream",  StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 5, 0,0,0), EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 9, 0,0,0), SnapshotID = 5}
                }
            };

            var groups = (from s in db.Snapshot
                          join c in db.Campaign on s.Id equals c.SnapshotID
                          select new { snapshot = s, campaign = c }
                           )
                           .GroupBy(x => x.snapshot.Id)
                           .ToList();

            var results = groups.Select(x => new
            {
                snapshot = x.First().snapshot,
                campaign = x.GroupBy(y => y.campaign.CampaignName).Select(y => y.First().campaign).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class DataBase
    {
        public List<Snapshot> Snapshot { get; set; }
        public List<Campaign> Campaign { get; set; }
    }
    public class Snapshot
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string DatasetID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Campaign
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CampaignName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public int SnapshotID { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: i could not be able to test it because the view crushed as it expects to receive a model `@model IEnumerable<campaign.Models.Campaign>` and if i comment out at the `var results` the  `snapshot = x.First().snapshot,` the return type will be a list of campaigns. 
i tried to add the `.AsEnumerable()` but again it returns a list of campaigns. how can it be done ?

Also, until i test it. can you tell me how you _distinct_ the campaignName column? because i did not see the distinct command

Comment: I changed code and got rid of the filter for start/end date.  Then GroupBy CapaignName and took first for each Campaign Name.

Comment: can you check my new answer? i have included screenshots of my initial results and how i want to be the final result. i have also configured a query. could you check it and improve it or provide another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

[Initial Result without distinct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Isv.jpg)

I configured the query: `var campaigns = db.Campaigns.Include(c => c.Snapshot) .GroupBy(i => i.Snapshot.DatasetID).AsEnumerable() .SelectMany(i =>i.DistinctBy(z=>z.CampaignName));` which does the distinct that i want but this time does not display me the value of the DataSetID
[New Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdUI6.jpg)

This time, how can i display the DataSetID value ?

[This is the View .cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk0vF.jpg)

Comment: Look at i.Key which is the DataserID : SelectMany(i =>new {CampaignName = i.DistinctBy(z=>z.CampaignName), DatasetID = i.Key})

Comment: @jdweng if i add the query you mentioned i have the following compile error

_The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly._

Comment: Try following :.SelectMany(i =>i.DistinctBy(z=>z.CampaignName).Select(x => new {Distinct = x, DatasetID = i.Key}))

Comment: @jdweng now compiles but when the page open it crashes. i have the following excemption _The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`2[campaign.Models.Campaign,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[campaign.Models.Campaign]'`._
the query you provided returns an `IEnumerable<'a>campaigns`. 
shall i change the `@model IEnumerable<campaign.Models.Campaign>` which is at the .cshtml file ?

Comment: From my point of view i expect to receive an `IEnumerable<Campaign>campaigns` so that in my .cshtml file to use `@model IEnumerable<campaign.Models.Campaign>`

Comment: The DataSetID is in snaphot and you model is only returning Campaign so of course you will get an exception.

Comment: @jdweng according your query how the `@model IEnumerable<campaign.Models.Campaign>`  should it modified ?


if i mouse over the `var campaigns = etc.` it says that it returns `IEnumerable<'a>campaigns`

Comment: What is returned should be the same as when you did not use distinct.

Comment: @jdweng however as mentioned according to the outcome it is not the same. what should i do ?

Comment: Why are you using IEnumerable<campaign.Models.Campaign>?  just make 'var'

Comment: @jdweng `@model IEnumerable<campaign.Models.Campaign>` is declared at the beginning of the view razor page. with `var` as you said what is the correct syntax ?

Comment: You view has to include Capaign and SnapshotID.  You cannot use for the view IEnumerable<campaign.Models.Campaign> because it does not include SnapshotID.  Create a new view type.

Comment: @jdweng yes right. so i have to do a new class which will contain: `public Campaign campaign {get; set;}` and a `public string SnapshotID {get; set;}` right? 
or it has to be a `List<Campaign> Campaign`  ?

Comment: @jdweng thanks. I have just created the appropriate class, passed it onto the View.cshtml file and produces the desired outcome.
could you give me a brief explanation on your second select statement ? `.Select(x => new OkViewModel { campaign = x, dataset = i.Key })` from my notes and some online reading i did not see any example `i.Key` . could you enplane me how that works and produce the datasetID ? cause that DatasetID is the foreign key. if arbitrary have seen that i would think that brings the primary key ID

Comment: i.Key is only created when you use GroupBy and is the value(s) that are used to perform the grouping.

Comment: @jdweng yes, correct. i knew it but i did not know how to use that key. I will further do some experiments with some queries and either i will ask you here so that if possible to give some explanations or i will directly create a new Question.  Thanks again

Comment: The key is same type as object and can be used like any other linq object.  If you use new {...} in the GroupBy i may contain more than one object like i.Key.Name or i.Key[0].